# 5G Networks Disappeared from Network List

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, 802.11

All 5GHz networks have suddenly and inexplicably disappeared from the network list on my Windows 10 PC. Normal 2.4GHz band networks are still there. Have been connected in the past, always (stuff streamed over to other computers on a weekly basis from it) and the network adapter, of course, supports 5G band.

All other devices show the (multiple) 5G networks nearby, including my network. I'm not sure what else to do but roll back the most recent Windows Update... which happened yesterday, suspiciously around the same time this problem began as far as I know.

Would appreciate if anyone has any other solutions to try out. Never seen anything like this. I hate Windows.

**Tried:**

- resetting router
- restarting computer
- updating network adapter driver (tried 3 different ones)
- network troubleshooting on PC, which shows a generic problem with access point but nothing else, and gives no other feedback than "try
  resetting router"
- sfc /scannow because why not

Comment: Checked the Network Adapter settings to see if 5GHz has been turned off by accident?

Comment: Yah, shoulda mentioned that one. I don't even see a setting for it in the device manager properties for it. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: was there a driver update? I also had this years ago where WU installed a bad driver update

Comment: There definitely wasn't an update to the actual network adapter driver (I checked near the beginning), but I'll have to go through the most recent Windows update I got pushed and see what all is in it.